# PHP db2_prepare update failing

Tags: php, sql, db2, sql-update

Any time i execute the below code, ZendServers logs the error shown below.  The library KIVATEST does exist, the file ORTXNPF does exist, and I am able to execute a select statement against this file just fine...

---

[18-May-2011 21:30:40] PHP Warning:  db2_prepare() [function.db2-prepare]: Statement Prepare Failed in /www/zendserver/htdocs/dev/Merchandising/ResultSetTesting.php on line 38

[18-May-2011 21:30:40] PHP Warning:  db2_execute() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /www/zendserver/htdocs/dev/Merchandising/ResultSetTesting.php on line 39

[18-May-2011 21:30:40] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not execute' in /www/zendserver/htdocs/dev/Merchandising/ResultSetTesting.php:40

Stack trace:
        #0 {main}
          thrown in /www/zendserver/htdocs/dev/Merchandising/ResultSetTesting.php on line 40

---

```
    $connection = db2_connect ( "*LOCAL", "", "" );
    if (! $connection) {
        Throw New Exception('Could not connect');
    }

    //Prepare and execute the SQL statement.
    [[LINE 38]]  $stmt = db2_prepare ( $connection, "UPDATE KIVATEST.ORTXNPF SET otbfnm = 'AdamTest' where ottxn# = 216807" );
    if (! db2_execute ( $stmt ) ) {
        Throw New Exception('Could not execute');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why the error provided was so un-helpful... but the problem turned out to be that the user had *USE authority to the file, but not *ALL... so i was able to SELECT but not UPDATE.

Comment: have to love the useful error messages!  Glad you were able to resolve it!